# Low accuracy in facial recognition model

Tags: python, face-recognition

I am running the code provided by Adrian in this link https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/25/raspberry-pi-face-recognition/#comment-473194. 
I have a dataset containing 6 faces of 3 people each. I ran this code and it works fine when detecting my face and my friend’s face. It faces trouble while detecting the third person’s face. It detects it as my face. Does this algorithm work only for binary classification? Will the accuracy improve if I improve if I make the dataset bigger?

Answer (score 0):

If you increase your database. It will increase the accuracy for sure. Also opencv is not a good solution if you want to detect a face in real time for the sake of accuracy.Cause, when an object is moving, then the cascade function shows some kind of miss classification.

However you can use dlib function to make your processing robust.  Or you can use yolo for face recognition.